# Placing two divs on the same line with 'inline' not working

Tags: html, css

I have several buttons contained within divs that I would like to place on the same line. Two of the buttons are only displayed if a certain value is greater than 0. I added `display:inline-block` in a div container thinking that would place all of the enclosed divs on the same line but it didn't. I also need the buttons to float right (hence the `style="float:right` in the container div. I've also tried placing `display=inline` on each of the buttons which didn't work. Here is my HTML:

```
<div style="display:inline-block" style="float: right;">
    <div *ngIf="menu.itemNumber > 0">
        <button pButton type="button" label="Download" icon="fa-wrench" iconPos="left" (click)="Download();"></button>
        <button pButton type="button" label="Upload" icon="fa-wrench" iconPos="left" (click)="Upload()"></button>
    </div>
    <button pButton type="button" style="float: right;" label="Delete" icon="fa-wrench" iconPos="left" (click)="Delete()"></button> 
</div>
```

Why aren't the buttons showing up on the same line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you have a `div` inside which is `block` by default. Apply `display:inline-block` to all elements inside parent button div

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.main>* {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
  </div>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inner `div` (`<div *ngIf="menu.itemNumber > 0">`) is still a block level element.  You need to give it `display: inline-block`, for it to be inline with the following button.

Also, do not duplicate the `style` property on your wrapper `div`.  Combine the styles in one string: `style="display:inline-block; float: right;"` (this is assuming you still want the outer `div` to be `inline-block` - it may not need to be).

Answer (score 1):

I also learned that sometimes, depending on the size of the content inside your buttons, or sibling elements, they might not be in the same baseline, meaning some will be higher than others, even if they are side by side. The way to fix baseline issues is to use a special kind of overflow (Like hidden or auto) on the sibling elements
EXAMPLE:

```
div sibling-elements{
 overflow: hidden;
}
```